# What is the Ancient Rig Vedic Rivalry with Vashishta Maharishi and Vishwamitra Maharishi

Tags: rig-veda, vashishta, vishwamitra

I'm referring to the Battle of 10 Kings and the rift caused between them due to the actions of King Sudas